# Como Instalar o make no MSYS2

Tags: linux, windows, make, cygwin, msys2

Estou precisando de diversos comandos usados com o Linux em meu ambiente windows, e apesar da Microsoft estar liberando um novo shell baseado no Ubuntu eu não fiquei muito satisfeito com os resultados e optei em usar o MSYS2, eu já usei o CygWin, mas também não estava mais satisfeito com seu resultado, muitos problemas relativos ao Path e me parece que o MSYS2 está melhor.

Mas não consegui achar o `make` como faço para instala-lo?

Answer (score 0):

Apesar desta pergunta ser antiga, ela ainda é feita por muitos que usam o MSYS2.

Eu passei a usa-lo este ano em substituição ao CygWin, e estou ficando bem satisfeito.

Hoje tive a necessidade de instalar o `make` e não sabia como e comecei a pesquisar, cheguei a esta pergunta mas não deu certo, e continuei minha pesquisa então acabei lendo todo o manual do MSys2 e somei ao conhecimento coletado em outros posts.

Tudo é muito simples como sempre (depois que aprendemos)

Para instalar o make no msys, basta entrar no shell do msys e digitar os comandos para atualizar o shell, isso é bom caso esteja com alguma instalação antiga então digite os comandos abaixo e confirme para que a atualização seja feita:

```
pacman -Sy pacman
pacman -Syu
pacman -Su
```

Nos três comandos acima se for preciso feche a janela e reabra para cada um.

Agora para instalar o make e este funcionar sem muita mágica basta digitar:

```
pacman -S msys/make
```

Pronto você já tem o make do msys2 disponível em seu windows.